# Removing String from date comming from Oracle12c db

Tags: php, oracle12c

So i need a list of dates comming from database for my app. The thing is i just need the time not date but im unable to remove its string.

ive used this in my other tables but for some reason its not working with this api im using php.
substr($row['DATEFROMTABLE'], 9 , strlen(($row["DATEFROMTABLE"]))-0)

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( VISIT_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEFROMTABLE
               FROM tablename t
               LEFT JOIN  anothertable d ON t.column=d.column
               WHERE t.anothercolumn IS NULL AND  t.somedate >= TO_DATE('23-JUL-2019 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
               AND t.somedate <= TO_DATE('23-JUL-2019 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND t.column='somedata here' 
               ORDER BY VISIT_DATE


$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$row=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$products = array();
$newarr=count($row);
for($k=0;$k<$newarr;$k++)
{


substr($row[$k], 2 , strlen($row[$k])-8);


array_push($products,$row[$k]);
}

echo json_encode($products);
```

[
    {
        "DATEFROMTABLE": "23-JUL-19 11:30:00"
    },
    {
        "DATEFROMTABLE": "23-JUL-19 11:45:00"
    },
    {
        "DATEFROMTABLE": "23-JUL-19 12:00:00"
    },
    {
        "DATEFROMTABLE": "23-JUL-19 12:15:00"
    },
    {
        "DATEFROMTABLE": "23-JUL-19 12:30:00"
    },
    {
        "DATEFROMTABLE": "23-JUL-19 12:45:00"
    }
]
i need to remove date from this result

this is the result i get in postman

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by editing your SQL like the following:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( VISIT_DATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEFROMTABLE
...
```

Comment: you are a lifesaver dude thankyou that was easy i wasted an hour for nothing :P